# Nodejs Backend APIs, when dockerized, are taking more time to connect to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I moved my nodejs backend to docker(previously it was deployed on ec2 instance).

My mongodb is deployed on another ec2 instance, which i did't move to docker. (want to keep it this way only).

After dockerization of my backend,(Deployed it on ECS) APIs are taking longer time for db queries. Don't understand what went wrong. Or is it suppose to be like this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the issue here.

Due to different availability zone, It was taking more time. There was one extra hop causing extra time.